# Dependent features configured but no package ID was set

Tags: android, debugging, pack

I am using two modules for two apps like user app and admin app. all were working perfectly on debugging. But suddenly an error showing on debugging like **"Dependent features configured but no package ID was set."** And I can't debug now. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please check

app module:

```
plugins{
    id "com.android.application"
    ...
}
```

library module:

```
plugins{
    id "com.android.library"
    ...
}
```

They use different plug in and you need to be careful whenever you use multiple modules.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem. All other solutions to this assume the second module is a library, but mine needs to be an app module. I solved it by adding **configuration:'default'** to the implementation project dependency:

```
 implementation project(path: ':app:your_module_name', configuration:'default')
```